# Is there any subset in $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that...

Tags: general-topology

The intersection with every line L in $\mathbb{R^2}$ is open in $L$ with the topology

$\mathcal{T}_L = \{G\cap L : G \text{ open in } \mathbb{R^2} \text{ with the Euclidean Topology } \} $, but the set **is not** open in $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the Euclidean Topology ?

I couldnt find and such set but am pretty sure that there exist such a set , if you have any ideas let me know ! thanks in advance !

Comment: Consider the origin together with an open interval (0,t) in direction t as t ranges from 0 to $2 \pi$.

Comment: @IttayWeiss then its intersection with the line in direction t would be the interval [0,t), which is not an open subset of the line?

Comment: Yes i also think that this example doesnt work :(

Comment: @IttayWeiss Ok i understand what you mean something like this $A = \cup_{\theta \in [0,2\pi]}A_\theta $ such that $A_\theta = \{(r \cos\theta,r\sin\theta) : r \in [0,\theta)\}$ then $A$ is not open in $\mathbb{R^2}$ but open in $L$ for every lane L.

Comment: Another example: take a parabola, remove one point, then take the complement.

Comment: yea seems to be working ! nice !

Answer (score 1):

(*To kick it from the unanswered queue*)

Summarizing the comments:

Take $A=\Bbb R\setminus P$
 where $P$ is a parabola with one point removed.

Answer (score 1):

By a classical result of Mazurkiewicz cited in [this paper by Mauldin](http://www.math.unt.edu/~mauldin/papers/no100.pdf), assuming the axiom of choice there is a so-called "$2$-point set", i.e., a set $S\subset\mathbb R^2$ which intersects every line in exactly two points. In particular a $2$-point set intersects every line in a closed set, so its complement has your property, it intersects every line in a relatively open set.

By a result of Larman quoted in [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272527/can-two-point-sets-be-borel), a $2$-point set can't be an $F_\sigma$ set,
so its complement can't be a $G_\delta$ set, much less an open set. It can easily be arranged that the
$2$-point set is not even a Borel set, and in fact it's a well known open problem whether a $2$-point set **can** be a Borel set.